# Is it possible to isolate the variable X in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$P = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+xac+a^2}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+xbc+b^2}}$

Comment: Move one of the fractions to the other side to get $P= 1/\texts[stuff}$  on the left. Square both sides. That will leave one radical on the left. Isolate it and square again. Then you will have a fourth degree equation in $x$ you may be able to work with.

Comment: I think the tag abstract-algebra does not apply in this case. I am assuming that $+$ refers to addition and this question has nothing to do with groups and rings.

Comment: @user376343 Yes. Should be $P -$ instead of $P =$. Moot since there's an answer along these lines below.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Squaring your $P$ you will get
$$P^2=\frac{1}{x^2+acx+a^2}+\frac{1}{x^2+bcx+b^2}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+acx+a^2}\sqrt{x^2+bcx+b^2}}$$. Now we can write
$$P^2-\frac{1}{x^2+acx+a^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+bcx+b^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+acx+a^2}\sqrt{x^2+bcx+b^2}}$$
Now you must square again.
Good luck!
$${P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{4}{x}^{4}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{c}^{3}{x}
^{3}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{3}{c}^{3}{x}^{3}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}b{c}^{3}{
x}^{5}+2\,{P}^{4}a{b}^{2}{c}^{3}{x}^{5}+{P}^{4}{a}^{4}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}{x
}^{2}+4\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}{b}^{3}{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+4\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}b{c}^{2}
{x}^{4}+{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{4}{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+4\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c
}^{2}{x}^{4}+{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}{x}^{6}+4\,{P}^{4}a{b}^{3}{c}^{2}{x}
^{4}+4\,{P}^{4}ab{c}^{2}{x}^{6}+{P}^{4}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}{x}^{6}+2\,{P}^{4
}{a}^{4}{b}^{3}cx+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{4}bc{x}^{3}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}{b}^{4}c
x+4\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}{b}^{2}c{x}^{3}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{3}c{x}^{5}+4\,{P}^{4
}{a}^{2}{b}^{3}c{x}^{3}+4\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}bc{x}^{5}+2\,{P}^{4}a{b}^{4}c
{x}^{3}+4\,{P}^{4}a{b}^{2}c{x}^{5}+2\,{P}^{4}ac{x}^{7}+2\,{P}^{4}{b}^{
3}c{x}^{5}+2\,{P}^{4}bc{x}^{7}+{P}^{4}{a}^{4}{b}^{4}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{4}
{b}^{2}{x}^{2}+{P}^{4}{a}^{4}{x}^{4}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{4}{x}^{2}+4
\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{x}^{4}+2\,{P}^{4}{a}^{2}{x}^{6}+{P}^{4}{b}^{4}
{x}^{4}+2\,{P}^{4}{b}^{2}{x}^{6}+{P}^{4}{x}^{8}-2\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}b{c}^
{3}{x}^{3}-2\,{P}^{2}a{b}^{2}{c}^{3}{x}^{3}-4\,{P}^{2}{a}^{3}b{c}^{2}{
x}^{2}-4\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}{x}^{2}-2\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}
{x}^{4}-4\,{P}^{2}a{b}^{3}{c}^{2}{x}^{2}-8\,{P}^{2}ab{c}^{2}{x}^{4}-2
\,{P}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}{x}^{4}-2\,{P}^{2}{a}^{4}bcx-4\,{P}^{2}{a}^{3}{
b}^{2}cx-4\,{P}^{2}{a}^{3}c{x}^{3}-4\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{b}^{3}cx-8\,{P}^{
2}{a}^{2}bc{x}^{3}-2\,{P}^{2}a{b}^{4}cx-8\,{P}^{2}a{b}^{2}c{x}^{3}-6\,
{P}^{2}ac{x}^{5}-4\,{P}^{2}{b}^{3}c{x}^{3}-6\,{P}^{2}bc{x}^{5}-2\,{P}^
{2}{a}^{4}{b}^{2}-2\,{P}^{2}{a}^{4}{x}^{2}-2\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{b}^{4}-8
\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{x}^{2}-6\,{P}^{2}{a}^{2}{x}^{4}-2\,{P}^{2}{b}^
{4}{x}^{2}-6\,{P}^{2}{b}^{2}{x}^{4}-4\,{P}^{2}{x}^{6}+{a}^{2}{c}^{2}{x
}^{2}-2\,ab{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+{b}^{2}{c}^{2}{x}^{2}+2\,{a}^{3}cx-2\,{a}^{2
}bcx-2\,a{b}^{2}cx+2\,{b}^{3}cx+{a}^{4}-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+{b}^{4}
=0$$

Comment: If you square the given equation again you will get a polynomial in degree six, to solve this you will need a numerical method.